# Why CMake does not seem to apply -pthread using add_compile_options command?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, cmake

I am trying to compile a simple C++ program using g++ 4.8.2 using CMake 2.8.12.2 which makes use of C++11 features and also multithreading. For that, compiler flags -std=c++11 and -pthread must be used. From my understanding, in CMake, setting these flags can be done in various ways, one is to use the set command:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")
```

The other (supposedly preferred) way is to use add_compile_options command:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
add_compile_options(-pthread)
```

(Or in one line: `add_compile_options(-std=c++11 -pthread)`)

So, the problem is that in my case, only the first method works - by using the set command. The problem is with using the add_compile_options which results in crash of the compiled output executable with the following message (just like the -pthread was not specified at all):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code I test with:

```
#include <future>

int main()
{
    auto a = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){});
    a.wait();
    return 0;
}
```

From the fact that this program compiles, I can infer that -std=c++11 was applied. The question is that why -pthread is not applied?

Comment: May help if you share your compile line output. Can you see these flags on it for the objects you're compiling?

Comment: Ok, didn't know I can see it but I can ideed when I execute `make -n`. With add_compile_options the compilation command is:
`/usr/bin/c++    -g   -pthread -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.o -c /home/batman/stuff/testprojects/test/main.cpp`
With set, the command is:
`/usr/bin/c++    -pthread -std=c++11 -g   -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.o -c /home/batman/stuff/testprojects/test/main.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are definitely compiling with g++ (just worth clarifying by checking what `/usr/bin/c++` actually is - I'm presuming it's a link to g++) The man page for g++ gives:

```
gcc [-c|-S|-E] [-std=standard]
    [-g] [-pg] [-Olevel]
    [-Wwarn...] [-pedantic]
    [-Idir...] [-Ldir...]
    [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro]
    [-foption...] [-mmachine-option...]
    [-o outfile] [@file] infile...
```

which implies that you need to have:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -pthread ...
```

in that order.

Perhaps it's worth trying running your command line manually with this adjustment to see if what's produced works as you'd expect.

It looks to me (without any research, I'd add) that `add_compile_options` might only be useful for adding strict compiler options, so you *might* have to use `set` to set `-std=c++11` and `add_compile_options` for all other compiler options - i.e. specified after `-g`

Comment: I think I understand now what's going on. If I set the -std=c++11 using add_compile_options but -pthread like this: `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pthread")` then the application runs without the error. My hypothesis is that -pthread is a linker flag but CMake does not pass the add_compile_options to linker, so it has to be added separately. And why setting both flags to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS works is that then both flags (-std=c++11 and -pthread) are added to both stages - compilation and linking.

Comment: Okay, even better way to add -pthreads is to use target_link_libraries command like this: `target_link_libraries(projectname -pthread)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
set (
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "
  "-Wall -Werror -pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed"
)
```

source: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201)